# Geometry of directional derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose, the question is to find the directional derivative of f(x, y) = $xe^{xy}$ at (-3,0) in the direction of vector v = {2,3}. I know, the answer is $\frac {29}{\sqrt13}$ from the conventional way. But my professor asks me to explain the geometry aspects of the question (preferably with pictures), which I don't really understand. So far, I have only come up with one sentence: "If a thing moves from the point (-3,0) to the vector v = {2, 3}, so the speed of the movement of the thing is $\frac {29}{\sqrt13}$." Is it right? Or is there any other answer, which is more of an in-depth analysis of the question? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the interpretation is not correct. I'd say something like: If you are standing in the surface $z = xe^{xy}$ above the point $(-3,0)$ and move along the direction of $(2,3)$ one unit, you'll be approximately $29/\sqrt {13}$ units above the height $z$ you were before.

Answer (score 0):

A thing moving from a point to a vector sounds inconsistent, so let's revise.  The thing moves from the point and *along the direction* of the vector.

For a geometric explanation: the gradient of the function at a point $x$ is a vector, $\nabla f(x)$.  The direction of vector $\nabla f(x)$ is the direction in which the function increases the fastest.  The magnitude of $\nabla f(x)$ is that highest rate at which the function increases.

If we now consider any other vector, $v$, emanating from point $x$, we ask, How quickly does the function increase along $v$?

We answer this question by comparing the rate of increase along $v$ to the rate of increase along $\nabla f(x)$.  The comparison is carried out by calculating **the component of $\nabla f(x)$ along $v$**, which is the dot product
$$
v \cdot \nabla f(x).
$$
And this dot product is exactly the definition of the directional derivative along $v$.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your professor wants you to use the Pythagorean Theorem:  Calculate the derivatives in the $x$ and in the $y$ directions, then form (and draw) a triangle whose hypotenuse is in the desired (specified) direction and use the Theorem to find the magnitude of the derivative in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the more general interpretation. The user @rrogerr gives an excellent interpretation of your particular result. Here $f$ is a continuous function about $p = (-3,0)$ and so we can choose a connected neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in which the graph of $f|_{U}$ is nice and connected. Think of the image below.

[image]

Let $G(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y))$ for. In computing the direction derivative of $f$ in the direction of some vector $\vec{v}$, we think if taking the image of the line $p+tv$ i.e $G(p+tv)$ which is a curve segment on the graph for $|t|< \delta$. Again, see the image below.

[image]

For this curved segment $G(p+tv)$, we see that the direction derivative is just the slope of the tangent line at $p' = G(p+t_0v)$ for some fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

[image]

For differentiable functions $f$ like the one you have, the interpretation of the directional derivative as the slope of the tangent line to a graph leads one to say,

$$ D_v f(p) = \nabla f(p) \cdot v$$

This is due to the fact that we know the linearization of $f$ approximates the graph of $f$ in a small neighborhood for points in the domain in which $f$ is differentiable i.e,

$$f(x,y) \approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) \Delta y + f(p)$$

where $(x,y)$ is sufficiently close to $p$. Hence we have,

$$ f(x,y) - f(p) \approx \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) &\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \Delta x \\ \Delta y \end{pmatrix}$$

Since $(x,y)$ are just points sufficiently close to $p$, if we wish to compute the change in $f$ in direction $v$, we let $(x,y) = (p_1+t_0v_1,p_2+t_0v_2)$ where $p = (p_1,p_2)$. And so $(\Delta x, \Delta y) = t_0v$. Therefore we have,

$$ \frac{f(x,y) - f(p)}{t_0} \approx \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) &\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Leading us to the following,

$$ D_v f(p)=\lim_{t_0 \to 0} \frac{f(p+t_0v)- f(p)}{t_0} = \nabla f(p) \cdot v$$